# Trigger Grid row validation when selection of cell editor LookUpEdit changes

Tags: c#, validation, gridview, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a `DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl` which has a column using `DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemLookUpEdit` as cell editors.

When I select an item from the LookUpEdit, this does not cause any validation but does nothing until I click anywhere to make the Grid lose focus.

My desired behaviour would be that changing the LookUpEdit's selection immediately triggers a row validation event of the Grid.

How could this be achieved?

The [official DevExpress Documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument749) tells to call the GridView's `UpdateCurrentRow` method:

> There may be cases when you need to implement row validation. [...] To do so, handle the `ColumnView.ValidateRow` event. Note that you can also initiate row validation manually by calling the `ColumnView.UpdateCurrentRow` method.

I did this in the GridView's `ValidatingEditor` event handler:

```
private void gridView1_ValidatingEditor(object sender,BaseContainerValidateEditorEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as GridView).UpdateCurrentRow();
}
```

However, now I can't add new rows to the Grid any more as end-user.

What would be the correct approach?

---

**Update:**

I am now listening to the GridView's `CellValueChanging` event and handling it like this:

```
private void gridView_CellValueChanging(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gv = (sender as GridView);
    gv.CellValueChanging -= gridView_CellValueChanging;  // detach this event handler
    gv.ActiveEditor.EditValue = e.Value;  
    gv.CellValueChanging += gridView_CellValueChanging;  // re-attach handler
    gv.CloseEditor();
}
```

I am sure this is not the way how one should do it, but it works for existing rows. However, it does not work on the "new row" - I still have to click anywhere else to apply changes that create a new entry. I want a new row to be created as soon as any cell of the "new row" got edited.

Answer (score 0):

The editor in the cell is still open, you have to close it.

```
private void lookup_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gvMyGrid.CloseEditor();
    gvMyGrid.UpdateCurrentRow();
}
```

Comment: Nope, this does not work. And when I handle the `ValidatingEditor` event, the editor seems already to be closed - at least it has no effect. I found a code snippet that works on existing rows but not on the new row and added it to my question. However, I want it to handle the new row equally. It also looks very dirty as well. Would you have a look, please?

Comment: Don't put this code to ValidatingEditor, put it somewhere else (cellvaluechanging, lookupeditor's Closed...)

Comment: If I put it into `CallValueChanging` it cancels the edit instead of applying it. That means no matter what I select in the LookUpEdit, it always immediately resets to the previous value. Therefore I needed to set the `EditValue` manually in my code. That however would cause another `CellValueChanging` event which leads to endless recursion resulting in a StackOverflowException. That's why I have this ugly  un- and re-subscribing to the event in my handler. But it does not work on the "new row" at all anyway .